# Cambiar la ruta de mi archivo de applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring

He creado un pequeño proyecto para poder utilizar el archivo **applicationContext** de Spring. Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando utilizo el siguiente codigo para levantar el contexto no tengo ningun problema:

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Empleado empleado4 = context.getBean("director", Empleado.class);
        System.out.println("Usando context: " + empleado4.getTareas());

        context.close();
```

Pero esta ves quiero ubicar el archivo applicationContext.xml en una ruta distinta, cree la siguiente estructura en la raiz del proyecto: META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml

Y trato de levantar el archivo con el siguiente codigo:

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
        Empleado empleado4 = context.getBean("director", Empleado.class);
        System.out.println("Usando context: " + empleado4.getTareas());

        context.close();
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [../META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [../META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Mi pregunta es: Como podria invocar a ese archivo **applicationContext.xml** desde otra ruta distinta en mi codigo java.

Comment: ¿Has probado con */spring/applicationContext.xml* o *spring/applicationContext.xml*? No estoy seguro pero puedes probar.

Comment: Si @EvgeniEnchev acabo de probar y me muestra el mismo error, yo he creado ambas carpetas WEB-INF y spring.

Comment: No sé como despliegas la aplicación pero mira el war o el directorio del despliegue si está tu fichero. Si no está, y está claro que se pierde, debes copiarlo, con maven o tu gestor favorito en la fase del empaquetado.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev es una aplicacion de escritorio un Main:


`public class EmpleadoMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  

  cargarContextoSpring();
  
 }
 
 public static void cargarContextoSpring() {
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/applicationContext.xml");
  Empleado empleado4 = context.getBean("director", Empleado.class);
  
  System.out.println("Usando context: " + empleado4.getTareas());
  context.close();
 }

}`

Comment: Estas utilizando algún gestor de proyectos como Maven, es Web tu proyecto?

Comment: @DrakoRod es un proyecto Java comun, no tiene dependencias, solo clases bean y una clase Main para correr el proyecto. Como puedes ver en la primera imagen

Comment: @BryanDuranCastañeda Pudieras extraer el directorio donde quieres invocar al applicationContext, y de ahí sumarle la ruta a una variable String cuando lo quieres llamar, puedes comenzar utilizando esto:

String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("The current working directory is " + currentDirectory);

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(currentDirectory + "/applicationContext.xml");

Checa si así te lo encuentra. me comentas como te va.

Comment: @DrakoRod lo implemente de la siguiente manera:

`public static void cargarContextoSpring2() {
  String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\META-INF\\spring\\"; 
  System.out.println("The current working directory is " + currentDirectory); 
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(currentDirectory + "applicationContext.xml"); 
  
  Empleado empleado4 = context.getBean("director", Empleado.class);
  
  System.out.println("Usando context: " + empleado4.getTareas());

 }`

Pero aun sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Estas en windows vdd? Tienes problema de enviarme el código drakorod1@gmail.com o subirlo a algún repositorio para darle una revisada?? En que IDE lo estas haciendo??

Comment: @DrakoRod Si, es windows. Te envio el codigo fuente por correo. Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Creo que para hacer lo que pretendes debes empaquetar tu proyecto en un jar y ejecutarlo. Tal como lo haces, con System.property etc no vas a conseguir mucho. Además no es la forma correcta de acceder al contexto de la aplicación. Y tampoco entiendo por qué no quieres que applicactionContext esté en el directorio de classes que es su sitio habitual.

Comment: @BryanDuranCastañeda ya revise tu código exactamente quiero saber porque necesitarías o estás implementando 2 applicationContext? tu aplicación la piensasn en algún caso multiplataforma o simplemente estas probando?

Comment: @DrakoRod solo he estado probando diferentes funcionalidades y propiedades del applicationContext por eso tengo dos archivos.

Comment: A ok, @BryanDuranCastañeda te recomendaría que usaras en este caso Maven para estructurar el proyecto, para que puedas incluir dentro del contexto de la aplicación (que con Maven es mas portatil entre plataformas y IDEs), sin que te cause mucho problema, en la noche te envío el ejemplo por correo y lo coloco como respuesta. Ya hice unas pruebas, y funciona bien (al menos en Linux tendrás que ajustarlo a Windows), pero no creo que te cause mucho problema.

Comment: Listo @DrakoRod, gracias por el apoyo :)